# FTP not working on FreeNAS

Tags: ftp, freenas

I'm trying to set up some client user accounts for FTP access to our FreeNAS server.

SFTP works, but FTP does not. E.g., I created a user `client`, with home folder `/mnt/raid-5x3/alpha/ftp/client1`

But when `client1` tries to log in, server returns `530 login incorrect` and log shows

```
Apr 19 20:53:51 whNAS proftpd[39911]: 192.168.1.99 ___ - notice: unable to use '~/' [resolved to '/mnt/raid-5x3/alpha/ftp/client1/']: Permission denied 
Apr 19 20:53:51 whNAS proftpd[39911]: 192.168.1.99 ___ - chroot to '~/' failed for user 'client1': Operation not permitted 
Apr 19 20:53:51 whNAS proftpd[39911]: 192.168.1.99 ___ - error: unable to set default root directory
```

I checked permissions:

```
root@whNAS /mnt/raid-5x3/alpha/ftp > ls -al 
total 107 
drwxrwxrwx 5  root    whstaff    6 Apr 19 20:06 ./ 
drwxrwx--- 18 root    whstaff   22 Apr 18 18:44 ../ 
drwxrwx--- 2  drew    whstaff    4 Dec 12 2012  .AppleDouble/ 
-rw-rw---- 1  jaclyn  whstaff 6148 Apr 18 15:53 .DS_Store 
drwxrwxrwx 2  client1 whclients 10 Apr 19 20:06 client1/ 
drwxr-xr-x 2  guest   whclients 10 Dec 11 2012  guest/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/mnt/raid-5x3/alpha/` is not executable for user `client1` or `whclients`, thus it cannot enter the path. Please check also the rest of the path, starting from `/`. Should better be executable for all.